# Newton Fractal, raízes da equação z^4=1

Tags: matlab

Estou querendo plotar um gráfico de uma imagem, chamada Newton Fractal:

[image: Newton Fractal]

Segue modelo:

O problema consiste em plotar as raízes da equação `z^4 = 1`, onde a mesma possui 4 raízes sendo (-1, 1, *i* e -*i*), onde para encontrar as raízes utilizo o método de Newton para fazer a aproximação.

As diferentes cores (vermelho, verde, amarelo ou azul) na imagem significa para qual raíz o método de Newton está se aproximando (e preto se não for a nenhuma), mas não estou conseguindo fazer o código que gera a imagem. Estou usando o scilab que é bem parecido com o matlab.

Segue o que eu consegui fazer:

```matlab
function [z] = f(x,y)
    clc
    f(x,y) = z^4 -1 = 0;
    f1(x,y) = 4*z^3;
    niter = 100;
    x0 = 0.5;

    for i=1:niter
        for j=1:niter;
    end

   [X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

    Z(i,j) = f(x(i), y(j) );
  end
end

surf(X,Y,Z)
endfunction.
```

Comment: Olha, eu pessoalmente não sei quase nada de matlab, mas olhando o seu código, me parece que o `end` do loop mais interno está no lugar errado.

Answer (score 2):

Feito no Matlab

```
%Cria matriz de valores iniciais
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-1:.002:1,-1:.002:1);
Z=X+i*Y;

%Cria funções
f=@(z) z.^4-1;
fp=@(z) 4*z.^3;

plot(Z,'.');

%NEWTON RAPHSON
for k=1:50
    Z=Z-f(Z)./fp(Z);
end

z=[1 i -1 -i]; %Raízes

%A matriz W contém o número da raíz que cada elemento Z converge 
W=5*ones(size(Z));%Cria matriz W

%Aproxima cada raiz
for k=1:4, 
    I=(abs(Z-z(k))<.3); 
    W(I)=k;
end 

%Cria o mapa de cores referentes as raizes
cmap=[0 0 1;1 0 0;0 1 0;1 1 0;0 0 0]; %[Azul;Vermelho;Verde;Amarelo;Preto]
%OS pontos que não convergem estarão em preto
%define o mapa de cores
colormap(cmap);
%Usando o mapa de cores cria imagem (W)
pcolor(X,Y,W),shading flat
```

E se quiseres deixar a imagem com sombras é só seguir o descrito no link

> http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/newton/

Para maiores informações:

> http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/257685